# log4j log content is being replaced

Tags: java, logging, log4j

now i am using log4j-1.2.9.jar for my application, but unfortunately when every 00:00 rolls the log file , my log content was being replaced ..

Here is log4j properties :

```
log4j.logger.my.com.myapps=ALL,cy
log4j.appender.cy=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cy.File=D:/CY/logs/cs.log
log4j.appender.cy.Append=true
log4j.appender.cy.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cy.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %t %c{3} :: %m%n
```

Yesterday my apps process was brought up at around 8 PM ++ ,then until 00:00 it will rolls to a new log file and rename the previous log file as cs.log-2013-07-25.

But now the problem comes, my log content from 8 PM ++ to 11:59 PM ++ was gone. It was overwritten. The log content become 12:00 AM - 12:40 AM in cs.log-2013-07-25.

Then other latest new log content after 12:40 AM is write to a new log in cs.log.

Any thought ? or my configuration is wrong ..

Comment: Might want to check this question out: http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-create-a-new-log-file-for-each-time-the-application-runs/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RollingFileAppender instead DailyRollingFileAppender.
Don't forget add property
log4j.appender.cy.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: If change to RollingFileAppender , will the log being rolled daily ?

Comment: no in that case it will depends on the max size that you are configuring for appender. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference between RollingFileAppender and DailyRollingFileAppender is that first one works on the basis of max log file size and the later one rotates on the basis of date and time frequency.

In your log4j.xml add these new properties to support RollingFIleAppender

```
  <param name="datePattern" value="'_'dd-yyyy-MM'.log'" />
  <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="4" />
  <param name="append" value="true" />
  <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10KB" />
```

I would suggest to go through these links.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

Thanks